# Linear independence of two linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

I was attempting the following exercise from Linear Algebra by Stephen et al.:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T$ and $U$ be nonzero linear transformations from $V$ into $W$. If $R(T) \cap R(U) = $ {$0$}, prove that {T, U} are a linearly independent subset of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$

My attempted solution was as follows: Suppose towards contradiction that $T, U$ are dependent. Then there exist scalars $a$ and $b$ not both zero such that $aT + bU$ is the zero function. This implies that $bU = -(aT)$, and since $T, U$ are nonzero linear transformations there must exist a vector $v$ such that $0 \neq U(v) = (b)^{-1}(-a)T(v) \in R(T)$ contradicting $R(T) \cap R(U) = \{ 0 \}$.

I was self-learning the material and so was hoping if anyone could kindly provide a sanity check on the general soundness of the proof and if critical details are missing.

Comment: You have to consider the case $b=0$.

Comment: No they don’t. You’re just being pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, assume $a=0$, you get $0+bU=0$, since $b\neq0$, this shows $U=0$, contradiction. Hence, we have $a\ne0\cap b\neq0$. Let $c=-b/a$, we get

$$U=\frac{1}cT$$

Since we are given $R(U)\neq 0$, there exsits $v\in V$, such that $U(v)\neq 0$, hence

$$T(v)=cU(v)=U(cv)\neq0$$

Can you deduce contradictions with $R(T) \cap R(U) = \{ 0 \}$ from here?

Answer (score 1):

We must show that $$aT+bU=0\implies a = b = 0$$

Note that the zero on the right hand side of the equation is the zero transformation, i.e. for all $v\in V$, $0(v)=0\in W$

Let $v\in V$ be given. $$(aT+bU)(v)=aTv+bUv=0(v)\implies aTv+bUv=0\in W$$

Suppose $a\ne 0$. Then $$aTv+bUv=0\implies Tv=-\frac{b}{a}Uv$$ but since the ranges of $T$ and $U$ only agree at zero, we get that $Tv=Uv=0$, contradicting the fact that the two transformations are non-zero. Therefore, $a=0$

This leaves $$bUv=0\implies b=0$$ because $U$ is non-zero.

Therefore, $a=b=0$ and $T$ and $U$ are linearly independent.